# Riddle from Frank Zappa and The Mothers of Invention

Tags: riddle, knowledge, poetry

As posed by Frank Zappa and Don Pardo on “Saturday Night Live” in 1976:

“I am gross and perverted 
I'm obsessed and deranged 
I have existed for years 
But very little has changed 
I'm the tool of the government 
And industry too 
For I am destined to rule 
And regulate you

“I might be vile and pernicious 
But you can't look away 
I make you think I'm delicious 
With the stuff that I say 
I'm the best you can get 
Have you guessed me yet? 
I'm the _____________

“You will obey me while I lead you 
And eat the garbage that I feed you 
Until the day that we don't need you 
Don't go for help ... no one will heed you 
Your mind is totally controlled 
It has been stuffed into my mold 
And you will do as you are told 
Until the rights to you are sold

“That's right, folks, [hint:]

> don't touch that dial!”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, this is an interesting idea for a puzzle! Is the answer

> Television?

My reasoning:

I am gross and perverted
I'm obsessed and deranged

> There has always been moral outrage over violent TV shows.

I have existed for years
But very little has changed
I'm the tool of the government
And industry too
For I am destined to rule
And regulate you

> For a long time there have been government PSAs and corporate advertisements playing on nearly every TV channel.

“I might be vile and pernicious
But you can't look away
I make you think I'm delicious
With the stuff that I say

> People enjoy watching TV and generally find arguments (especially ones that they already agree with) from pundits very convincing.

I'm the best you can get
Have you guessed me yet?
I'm the _____________

> Self explanatory.

“You will obey me while I lead you
And eat the garbage that I feed you
Until the day that we don't need you
Don't go for help ... no one will heed you

> Again, people like watching TV even if the content isn't intellectual.

Your mind is totally controlled
It has been stuffed into my mold
And you will do as you are told
Until the rights to you are sold

> Advertisements can be seen as "selling" viewers to companies.

Comment: Close enough for a cigar, @Deusovi ! The full answer in the song is "I'm the ____ ____ing ___ from your [answer you gave]. The clues above don't help narrow it down that much though.

Comment: Three words?  I thought it was "ooze running from your tv set".

Comment: Awesome that you got it without knowing the song.

Comment: So close, @Carl ! Zappa's just one step ahead of us. He used two words for [Deusovi's answer], used "[synonym for ooze] oozing" and threw in an "out." As seen on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NARfmp0PW4E and heard on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NeKrt4fc16I